# UF-naCMA not implies UF-CMA

Tags: public-key, authentication

I am trying to show that UF-naCMA doesn't imply UF-CMA. UF-naCMA is actually defined as UF-CMA but the adversary should send $q \in poly$ messages $m_i$ chosen non-adaptively (i.e. all at the same time) before obtaining the public key. Then, as in UF-CMA in order to win he has to forge a valid $(m^*,\sigma^*)$ with $m^*$ fresh.
I can see the implication doesn't hold intuitively but can't figure out an efficient attack to show it.
I thougth of showing textbook RSA is UF-naCMA would solve my problem but don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is likely to be Bellare et al's 1998 paper [Relations Among Notions of Security for Public-Key Encryption Schemes](https://www.di.ens.fr/david.pointcheval/Documents/Papers/1998_crypto.pdf). In particular, their theorem 3.7 shows that NM-CCA1 does not imply NM-CCA2. Their proof uses a NM-CCA1 safe scheme to construct a NM-CCA1 safe/NM-CCA2 vulnerable scheme (see page 18). UF-naCMA/UF-CMA and NM-CCA1/NMA-CCA2 are sort of the same problems but couched in the languages of signatures versus public key encryption.